# qt не вызывается слот в другом потоке

Tags: c++, qt

Имеется код:

main.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);


    QThread *testThread = new QThread;
    QWorker *worker= new QWorker();

    bool result;
    result = QObject::connect(testThread, &QThread::started, worker, &QWorker::process);
    qDebug()<<result;
    result = QObject::connect(worker, &QWorker::finished, testThread, &QThread::quit);
    qDebug()<<result;
    result = QObject::connect(worker, &QWorker::finished, testThread, &QThread::deleteLater);
    qDebug()<<result;
    result = QObject::connect(worker, &QWorker::finished, worker, &QWorker::deleteLater);


    QDataProducer* producer = new QDataProducer;
    result = QObject::connect(producer,&QDataProducer::setValue, worker,&QWorker::on_setValue);
    qDebug()<<result;
    result = QObject::connect(producer,&QDataProducer::stop, worker,&QWorker::on_stop);
    qDebug()<<result;
    worker->moveToThread(testThread);
    testThread->start();
    producer->getData();
    return a.exec();
}
```

main.h:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

class QWorker : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    int _value;
    bool _needExit;
public:
    QWorker()
    {
        _needExit=false;
    }
    ~QWorker(){}
public slots:
    void process(){
        while(!_needExit){
            printf("%d\n",_value);
            QThread::sleep(1);
        }
        emit finished();
    }
    void on_setValue(int val){
        _value=val;
    }
    void on_stop(){
        printf("Stop called!\n");
        _needExit=true;
    }

signals:
    void finished();
};


class QDataProducer: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QDataProducer(){}
    ~QDataProducer(){}
    void getData(){
        printf("Data producing started!\n");
        for(int val=0;val<10;val++){
            emit setValue(val);
            QThread::sleep(1);
        }
        printf("Stop emmited!\n");
        emit stop();
    }

public slots:

signals:
    void stop();
    void setValue(int value);
private:

};
#endif // MAIN_H
```

Связи между сигналами и слотами устанавливаются. В данном коде не вызываются слоты on_stop и on_setValue класса QWorker. Хотя согласно примерам из интернета, вызываться должны.Подскажите почему?

Comment: Я довольно бегло посмотрел, но, вроде бы, у тебя по старту потока вызывается метод Worker'а process. И в нём бесконечный цикл. Пока из него не выйдешь, никакие сигналы обрабатываться не будут. Разве что вызывать руками QCoreApplication::processEvents()  вызывать. Непонятно, зачем тебе вообще этот бесконечный цикл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтоб worker из другого потоко получил сигнал надо либо использовать `Qt::DirectConnection` пятым параметром в методе `connect` (он у вас `Qt::AutoConnection` по умолчанию), либо поднимать в потоке testThread `QEventLoop` и запускать цикл по обработке сообщений QEventLoop::exec(...) чтоб диспетчеризировать сигналы для объектов которые "живут" в этом потоке. Именно такой QEventLoop запускается в главном потоке внутри QApplication::exec(...)

Comment: testThread у него - стандартный QThread. Он его запустил start'ом. Зачем там что-то (QEventLoop) поднимать самому? Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: @Eventus, QThread это просто пото поток. Для того чтоб обрабатывать сообщения, а Qt::QueuedConnection это сигнал отправленный через сообщения, нужно запустить QEventLoop::exec() в потоке в бесконечном цикле.

Comment: я теперь совсем не понимаю, что ты хочешь сказать :)
Что мешает сделать: 1) засунуть объект в поток (moveToThread) 2) запустить Thread start'ом 3) Отправлять сигналы в соответствующие слоты объекту засунутому в поток без QEventLoop::exec() ?

Comment: @Eventus Тогда стоит разобраться как работают сигналы. В краце: Есть DirectConnection и QueuedConnection способы обработки сигнала, первый работает прямым вызовом колбэк функции в момент эмита сигнла, QueuedConnection отправляет служебное сообщение очередь потока к которому приписан объект и пока эта сообщение из очереди не будет обработано сигнал не дойдет до получателя. Для того чтоб обработать сообщение нужно создать QEventLoop объект (это и есть очередь) и вызвать exec() метод, это обработка сообщений. Когда ты запускаешь main, а внем QApplication::exec() .....

Comment: @Eventus (...продолжение...) Когда ты запускаешь main, а внем QApplication::exec() это и есть  запуск QEventLoop объекта, который хранится в QApplication. Таким образом у тебя начинают работать сигналы отправленные через QueuedConnection, но только в главном потоке. Для других потоков надо делать все ручками.

Comment: QueuedConnection'ы же себя неплохо ощущают с объектами просто помещёнными а QThread. Я не вдавался в подробности, но, видимо, QThread сам справляется с eventloop'ом и обработка сигналов идёт так, как нужно. Именно через очередь, а не прямым вызовом, и слот обрабатывается именно в потоке,в который был засунут объект, а не там где мы отправили ему сигнал. Проверенно неоднократно. Зачем запускать что-то где-то ручками, если QThread обо всём сам заботится? Или у меня какое-то глобальное недопонимание?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70264/discussion-between-eventus-and-ffk).

Comment: 1) Qt::DirectConnection не работает между потоками.
 *The slot is invoked immediately when the signal is emitted. The slot is executed in the signalling thread*

Comment: 2) Для того чтобы обрабатывать сигналы в другом потоке, не нужно запускай собственный  `QEventLoop`. Посмотрите хотябы на [стандартный пример использования `QThread`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qthread.html#details)

Answer (score 3):

Отвечу вопросом на вопрос. А сколько ждали? Предполагаю что меньше 10 секунд. Метод `QDataProducer::getData` "стопорит" главный поток на 10 секунд, а вместе с ним и цикл обработки событий. Пока этот метод выполняется сигналы из одного потока в другой не ходят, а накапливаются в очереди.

Костыльное решение, чтобы проверить мое предположение:

```
void getData(){
    printf("Data producing started!\n");
    for(int val=0;val<10;val++){
        qApp->processEvents(); //<-------------Запускаем обработку событий принудительно
        emit setValue(val);
        QThread::sleep(1);
    }
    printf("Stop emmited!\n");
    emit stop();
}
```

Разумеется в таком виде оставлять все нельзя. Придется все адекватно переделать. Как вариант, провести с `QDataProducer` те же манипуляции что и с `QWorker`, чтобы он тоже работал в отдельном потоке и не стопорил главный.

---

**P.S.** Сдался вам этот `QThread`? Чтобы его использовать нужно столько лишних телодвижений делать. Многопоточность сама по себе тема весьма сложная, а тут еще и с инструментом приходится бороться. Вот для примера как запустить метод в отдельном потоке при помощи [`QThreadPool`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html):

```
class RunProcess : public QRunnable{
    QWorker *_worker;
public:
    RunProcess(QWorker *worker):
        _worker(worker)
    {}
    void run(){
        _worker->process();
    }
};

//...

QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(new RunProcess(worker));
```

Но даже это решение может показаться многословным по сравнению [`QtConcurrent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html):

```
QtConcurrent::run(worker, &QWorker::process);
```

ИМХО можно привести следующие аналогии:

- `QThread` - острое и прочное лезвие без рукоятки. Да оно острое,
  да им можно разрезать все что угодно. Но придется быть очень
  аккуратным.
- `QThreadPool` - Обычный нож. В меру удобный, достаточно
  практичный.
- `QtConcurent` - Кухонный комбайн. Супер удобный. Сделает
  все за вас. Но как им почистить яблоко?

---

**P.P.S.** Если вы не разработчик Qt, перестаньте использовать приписку Q для своих классов. Это сбивает с толку. Я даже попытался загуглить `QDataProducer`. Эту букву застолбили авторы Qt потому что на момент начала разработки были какие-то трудности с нэймспэйсами, и это был единственный способ показать что класс относится к библиотеке Qt.

---

**P.P.P.S.** `printf` в C++ это не есть хорошо. Используйте `std::cout` или `QTextStream`. Они удобнее, у них есть типовая безопасность, их проще рефакторить.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. С сабжем разобрался, была блокировка, переделал архитектуру и все стало на места.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, цель стоит раз в указанное время делать определенное действие. Для этого случая подход неправильный - надо в объекте воркере делать слот, реализующий одно действие, делать таймер, к сигналу `timeout` таймера цеплять слот с действием, а при старте воркера просто запускать таймер.

По заданному вопрос - почему не вызываются слоты, в комментариях уже ответили, поток занят функцией `process` и сигналы встают в очередь и не обрабатываются. Руками теребонькать `processEvents` крайне нежелательно.